# python bottle - why is the simple template engine turning my dict into a list?

Tags: python, html, templates, bottle

I'm calling the template in the following route:

```
page = {"name": "welcome", "title": "Welcome", "icon": "/images/welcome-icon.png"}
contentOnly = request.query.get("contentOnly")
formRedirect = False
admin = is_admin()
announcments = get_announcments()
page = ""
if contentOnly:
  page += template("./views/welcome.tpl", contentOnly = contentOnly, announcments = announcments)
else:
  page += template("./views/header.tpl", page = page, admin = admin)
  page += template("./views/welcome.tpl", contentOnly = contentOnly, announcments = announcments)
  page += template("./views/footer.tpl", formRedirect = formRedirect)
```

When it hits this line in header.tpl:

```
%if page['name'] == "welcome":
```

It throws the following error:

```
File "/home/brett/projects/tastech website/development/views/header.tpl", line 5, in <module>
%if page['name'] == "welcome":
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `page` to an empty string, before calling the template:

```
page = ""
# ...
else:
    page += template("./views/header.tpl", page = page, admin = admin)
```

So within the template, `page` is set to `""`, the empty string.

Use a *different* name for the dictionary; `page_data`, perhaps:

```
page_data = {"name": "welcome", "title": "Welcome", "icon": "/images/welcome-icon.png"}
# ...
page = ""
# ...
else:
    page += template("./views/header.tpl", page=page_data, admin=admin)
```

Answer (score 1):

You set `page = ""`.  So page is a string.  Then you pass `page` to `header.tpl`.  Well, it's a string, and you can't index into a string with another string.

Solution: use a different name for your string than for your dict.

Answer (score 0):

You've overwritten the original dictionary called `page` with another variable, which is a string consisting of the concatenated template results. Call that something else.

Comment: Oh, drr, thanks. I thought I had edited the original page variable, not added a new one. I read that over a few times, can't believe I missed that. edit: Wait, no I didn't, forgot what I was even doing already!